# How to order by child / parent column with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

I have a table called `terms` which contains the following fields:

```
id | name | slug | taxonomy | parent_id
```

This is the current datasource:

```
id | name | slug | taxonomy | parent_id
 1   Pop    pop    category   null
 2   Rock   rock   category   null
 3   Jazz   jazz   category   2
 4   Edm    edm    category   3
```

Essentially I want return as result something like this:

```
Pop
Rock
— Jazz
— — Edm
```

Because `Jazz` and `Edm` are childs of `Rock`, so I wrote this:

```
return Term::where([
       'taxonomy' =>  'category'
   ])->orderBy('parent_id', 'ASC');
```

The problem's that when I order the Datatable by a specific column I doesn't get the desired order, and `Eloquent` will return the records ordered by the column selected eg:

```
column: name
order: desc
```

result:

```
Rock
Pop
— Jazz
— — Edm
```

Expected result:

```
Rock
— Jazz
— — Edm
Pop
```

**Term Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Cms\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Term extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Sluggable;

    protected $table = 'terms';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'taxonomy',
        'description',
        'parent_id',
        'term_group',
    ];

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Term::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function childs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Term::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Recursion**

```
function get_parent_term_name(Term $term, bool $root = true)
{
    $name = "";

    if (isset($term->parent)) {
        $name .= "— " . get_parent_term_name($term->parent, false);
    }

    return $root
        ? $name . " " . $term->name
        : $name;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a `parent()` and `children()` Relationship on your `Term` model? How are you loading the records recursively? To get that `-` and `- -`, your models need to be aware of how many Parent records they have. We're missing a lot of crucial information here.

Comment: @TimLewis I added the `Term` model and the recursion function that build the name with dash

Comment: check the already answered question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72900714/4369919

Answer (score 1):

Your `childs` relation needs to be recursive to achieve this, for this, you can first fetch all the parents i.e. the records with `parent_id = null` since they will be the only records exiting as a parent but not child.

**Term.php** Model

```
public function parent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Term::class);
    }

public function childs()
    {
        //Recursively call childs() relation treating each 
        //child as parent until no more childs remain
        return $this->hasMany(Term::class, 'parent_id')->with('childs');
    }
```

**TermsController.php**

```
return Term::where('parent_id',null)->with('childs')->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
```

This will give you a nested collection as:

```
0 => [
    id: 1,
    name: 'Pop,,
    slug: 'pop',
    taxonomy:'category',
    parent_id:null,
    childs: []
]

1 => [
    id: 2,
    name: 'Rock,,
    slug: 'rock',
    taxonomy:'category',
    parent_id:null,
    childs: [
        id: 3,
        name: 'Jazz,,
        slug: 'jazz',
        taxonomy:'category',
        parent_id:2,
        childs: [
            id: 4,
            name: 'Edm,,
            slug: 'edm',
            taxonomy:'category',
            parent_id:3,
            childs: []
        ]
    ]
]
```

`Note:` Your code must have a termination condition because according to your requirements and this solution, the tree might end up in an infinite loop (provided your database contains billions of records)

Comment: You can also add ordering in `childs()` relation, so you won't have to do this in controller.

Comment: I think OP is asking about ordering of main nodes, i.e., the ones with no parent, and not the childs, even if we don't use ```orderBy()``` here  it won't have any effect but I just left it there as is.

Comment: @SalmanMalik good solution but the main goal is to returns all the rows ordered as `parent -> child` 'cause I need to display in datatables. I'm currently using this plugin: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

Comment: I can't understand ```parent -> child``` do you have any visual representation of what you want to achieve here? Because from your original question you wanted a tree.

Comment: @SalmanMalik I need a tree, but actually the childs shouldn't be nested within the parent. I just need them ordered as a list without nesting anything in parent

Comment: @SalmanMalik gui example: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7567800/19011341/c5124098-87bc-11e6-8760-7c9afb01a0d7.png

another guy has asked this: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/775

don't know if him has achieved that

Comment: Well, fetching without nesting as a relation will be quite difficult since we will be uncertain about what relates what. So fetching it this way is our best bet right now. This nested data can however, be modified to generate the datable you require. Have you though about flattening the collection? try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59905720/12138592)

Comment: One flattened, the single array can easily be handled inside a single loop.

Comment: @SalmanMalik I looked for the solution of the other post and it's interesting. But could you help me to convert the result in a laravel eloquent query builder? otherwise it won't work for the yajra datatable. Also, next time use the the tag in the comment, or I wouldn't get the notification on stack overflow. Hurry up, bunty is expiring ...

Comment: @sfarzoso Hey, that answer is already well explained. I can't explain it any better. You have to define the helper functions and then simply call the methods in your controller class until the collection is flat. I can explain it to you but I don't really have enough time right now, and that by the way is a second problem so you might consider asking a solution for this in another post.

Answer (score -1):

orderByRaw('parent_id ASC, name Asc')